# Get element value in Razor with Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a foreach loop like that.I want to get item id when pressed "delete" button.

```
 <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name - Sirname</th>
                <th>Date - Time</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>id</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th>@(Model.Items.IndexOf(item)+1)</th>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.DateTime</td>
                    <td>@item.Message</td>
                    <td  id="itemId">@item.id</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

my Qjuery is like that;

```
        $("button").click(function () {
            var id = $("#itemId").html();
            $("#sonuc").html(id);
        });
    });
```

and my result must be in it;

```
<p id="sonuc"> </p>
```

But everytime it shows only first item's id of table. So how can i get value of each element in loop with Jquery?

Comment: You should never have multiple elements with the same id. ID must be unique

Comment: @Wazeed That would be a bad idea, since your solution with still result in him having  multiple elements with the same id

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, Yes that's a bad idea to have the same ID for multiple HTML elements. Better to go with a `class` or `data-attribute` for properly referring the element

Comment: @Wazeed I know that is why i said your suggestion was bad.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback. I have deleted that comment which contains bad suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `var id = $(this).parent().prev().text();`

**Demo**

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().prev().text();
  $("#sonuc").html(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name - Sirname</th>
      <th>Date - Time</th>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th>id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th>@(Model.Items.IndexOf(item)+1)</th>
      <td>@item.Name</td>
      <td>@item.DateTime</td>
      <td>@item.Message</td>
      <td>@item.id1</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>@(Model.Items.IndexOf(item)+1)</th>
      <td>@item.Name</td>
      <td>@item.DateTime</td>
      <td>@item.Message</td>
      <td>@item.id2</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<p id="sonuc"> </p>
```

Comment: @FurkanDURMUŞ No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique for each element and if you want to get value of Item Id and use razor after pressing delete button you can set value of Item Id on delete button as Id or data attribute so
you can try

> `<td  id="itemId_@item.id">@item.id</td>`
>
> `<button id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>`

instead of

> `<td  id="itemId">@item.id</td>`
>
> `<button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>`
>
> ```
>   $("button").click(function () {
>         var id = this.id; // value of itemId
>         
>     });
> });
> ```